# On Duplicate Update Mysql Error

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

```
 string ip_date = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("insert into ip_table (ip_addr,ip_date) values (@ip_addr,@ip_date) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ip_hitcount = ip_hitcount + 1 , ip_date = " + ip_date, con);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ip_addr", ipaddress);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ip_date", ip_date);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '02:04:50' at line 1 Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. Exception Details: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '02:04:50' at line 1
>   what is wrong with this code?

Comment: What is the error message that you get?

Comment: @JohnConde You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '02:04:50' at line 1
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '02:04:50' at line 1

Comment: Why use @ip_date for insert and not for the update part?

Comment: The script checks if an ip address already exists in the db if exists increments hitcount by 1 and if its a new ip it just insert into db along with ip_date

Comment: @shaiToro: I recommend you use the special **`VALUES`** function in the update portion, to reference the value supplied for the column in the insert. (I elaborate on this idea in my answer.)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the special `VALUES` function (in the update portion of the `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY` statement) to reference the value that was supplied for the column.

For example:

```
INSERT INTO ip_table (ip_addr,ip_date) VALUES (@ip_addr,@ip_date) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE ip_hitcount = ip_hitcount + 1 
     , ip_date = VALUES(ip_date)
                 ^^^^^^^       ^
```

### Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_values

This pattern fixes the syntax problem (the missing single quotes around the date literal in the SQL text), and it also clearly shows (in the SQL statement itself) that the value being assigned to the column is the value that was supplied in the INSERT statement, and is not being set to some *other* literal arrived at by some other mechanism.)

The pattern demonstrated also avoids having to supply an additional bind parameter, and (worse) incorporating a potentially unsafe value into the SQL text, possibly opening a SQL Injection vulnerability. (With this pattern, the SQL text is *static*, it's not dynamically generated with string concatenation operations.)

Comment: Interesting. I was not aware of this VALUES behavior

Comment: I've already did with "values". May be my syntax was incorrect. Ok let me try this!. Thanks !!!

Comment: @shaiToro: Note that the example statement is a complete, static string. There's no need for string concatenation. The expression `VALUES(ip_date)` refers to the *value* that was supplied for the `ip_date` column in the `INSERT` portion of the statement, the value that would have been assigned to the column if the INSERT had succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you just need to use the parameter @ip_date also for the UPDATE part

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(@"insert into ip_table 
                       (ip_addr,ip_date) values 
                       (@ip_addr,@ip_date) 
                       ON DUPLICATE KEY 
                       UPDATE ip_hitcount = ip_hitcount + 1, 
                       ip_date = @ip_date", con);
```

While this could be an edge case, using string concatenation to prepare sql statements is the sure way to hit errors like these or worse incur in an Sql Injection attack